# Using GCD to find unknown value

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Given the equation:

$ k = a(b-f) - ag$

If :

- a, b and f is unknown
- k is known
- ag is known
- a(b-f) is known

Can we find what a is?

Comment: Is the a value prime?

Comment: $a\,$ can be any common divisor of the known values $\,a(b-f)\,$ and $\,ag\ \ $

Comment: you forgot g in the unknowns otherwise you trivially can find it.

Comment: $100=150-50$. Can you work out $a$ from that, WeCan?

Comment: I can rule out a=4 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily directly. Because: $$\gcd(k,a(b-f))\geq a\tag{1}$$And,$$\gcd(k,ag)\geq a\tag{2}$$ And, $$\gcd(a(b-f),ag)\geq a\tag{3}$$

Gets us an upper bound on a, unless k has just 1 divisor less than this (1 is a divisor trivially sadly) we can't get an exact value yet. But, putting each possible a value through a similar test might help. Especially, if we can find $$\gcd((b-f),g)=1$$ forced that may help. **Edit**  if g is known (as of posting this edit it wasn't listed as unknown.) GCD isn't needed $${ag\over g}= a$$